# YouTube player state gives wrong result when multiple videos?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Im embedding youtube videos into a page and when the PlayerState changes (when the video is player or paused) im adding and removing the video-playing class to the container.

The following works fine when there is just 1 video. However if there are 2 videos then the class is added and almost immediately removed.

I think this is because the `window.YT.PlayerState` isnt limited the current video whos state has changed. How can I correct this scope?

Note, only 1 video will ever play at a time. The videos are in a carousel and are paused when you go to the next slide.

```
    if ($youtubeVideos.length) {
      var tag = document.createElement('script'),
        firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      tag.src = '//www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
        $youtubeVideos.each(function () {
          var player = new window.YT.Player(this.id, {
            events: {
              onReady: function (e) {
                var state = e.target.getPlayerState();
                if (state === window.YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING || state === window.YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                  $element.addClass('video-playing');
                  activePlayer = player;
                }
              },
              onStateChange: function (e) {
                if (e.data === window.YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING || e.data === window.YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                  $element.addClass('video-playing');
                  activePlayer = player;
                } else {
                  $element.removeClass('video-playing');
                  activePlayer = null;
                }
              }
            }
          });
        });
      };
    }
```

Comment: Can you use `e.target` instead of $element perhaps?

Comment: $element is the parent container. There is only 1 of these.

Comment: Aha.. but than you need to handle 4 cases, player1 plays and 2 is paused, 1 paused and 2 paused, 1 plays and 2 plays and lastly 2 plays and 1 paused. For each combination of states you need to decide which class you want to give to the parent.

Comment: The videos are in a carousel and when you go to the next slide are paused. So only 1 video will ever be playing.

Comment: Only one might be playing but multiple might be buffering. You need to check if the currentPlayer is buffering or playing, and only check for the remaining videos if they are playing I think. I will come back to it, could you provide a jsfidle so I can try myself?

Comment: I cant put my site online yet and I cant get it to work when I try and recreate in a jsfidle. Sorry I know thats not very helpful.